# TCP combine two messages when no ack is received

Tags: java

I want to send from the server (in java) two messages:

```
send: 0x01
Sleep: 5 seconds
send: 0x02
```

The client is an iPhone app, and sometimes, when the app is in background, it take 5-10 seconds to send server an ack, and TCP sends the first message AND the seconds message in ONE PACKET, it go's as following:

```
Time 00:00:00    server sends 0x01 - and wait for ack
Time 00:00:05    server not received ack and it needs to send the second message, so the server send: 0x01 0x02
```

Then the client don't know what this message mean, and sends FIN.

Any suggestions?

I've looked in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/socketOpt.html) page to find any option to avoid this chaining. May be you will find something related for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should disable the Nagle algorithm using [`Socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay%28boolean%29)
2. TCP is a stream-orientated protocol, not message based.  If your client app can't cope with stuff arriving in "odd" chunks then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: WOW.. Thanks! I didn't know what is Nagle algorithm at all.. After what I read about that it indeed seems to be my problem. can you explain what you mean by "If your client app can't cope with stuff arriving in "odd" chunks then you're doing it wrong."?

Comment: @uriel I mean that you should `read()` the amount of data you're expecting, and if you didn't get enough, keep reading til you do!  The data you write on one side is not guaranteed to come out one packet at a time.